# Why is the universal T&& constructor called when another constructor is more specific?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor-overloading, forwarding-reference

In the following snippet I have reconstructed a small failing example of what I'm working on right now. The class entity should be able to gobble up different "functor" types, hence it has an universal reference argument.

However, it seems that this template will even be called for when I clearly want to only use the copy constructor as in `entity a{n};` In my final code this leads to infinite recursion. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? I have even explicitely excluded the `entity` type from the overload, but to no avail...

[Demo](https://#include%20%3Ccstdio%3E%20#include%20%3Cutility%3E%20%20struct%20functor_t%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20void*%20something_;%20%7D;%20%20struct%20entity%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20entity()%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20functor_%20=%20new%20functor_t();%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20entity(functor_t*%20functor)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20:%20%20%20functor_%7B%20functor%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22entity(member_t)%5Cn%22);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Eentity()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20delete%20resource%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22%7Eentity()%5Cn%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20delete%20functor_;%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20template%20%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20requires%20(!std::same_as%3Cstd::remove_cvref%3CT%3E,%20entity%3E)%20%20%20%20%20entity(T&&%20other)%20%7B%20//%20%3C--%20why%20you??%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22entity(T&&)%5Cn%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20functor_%20=%20new%20functor_t(/*%20*/);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20entity(const%20entity&%20other)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22entity(const%20entity&)%5Cn%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20functor_%20=%20new%20functor_t(other.functor_);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20entity(entity&&%20other)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22entity(entity&&)%5Cn%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20functor_%20=%20new%20functor_t(std::move(other.functor_));%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20template%20%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20%20%20%20%20auto%20operator=(T&&%20other)%20-%3E%20entity&%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entity%7Bstd::forward%3CT%3E(other)%7D.swap(*this);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20*this;%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20auto%20swap(entity&%20other)%20-%3E%20void%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20std::swap(functor_,%20other.functor_);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20functor_t*%20functor_%20=%20nullptr;%20%7D;%20%20int%20main()%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20entity%20n;%20%20%20%20%20entity%20a%7Bn%7D;%20%20%20%20%20entity%20b;%20%20%20%20%20%20b%20=%20a;%20%20%20%20%20%20printf(%22--------------------%5Cn%22);%20%7D)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

struct functor_t
{
    void* something_;
};

struct entity
{
    entity()
    {
        functor_ = new functor_t();
    }

    entity(functor_t* functor)
        :   functor_{ functor }
    {
        printf("entity(member_t)\n");
    }

    ~entity() {
        // delete resource
        printf("~entity()\n");
        delete functor_;
    }

    template <typename T> requires (!std::same_as<std::remove_cvref<T>, entity>)
    entity(T&& other) { // <-- why you??
        printf("entity(T&&)\n"); 
        // functor_ = new functor_t(/* */);
    }

    entity(const entity& other) {
        printf("entity(const entity&)\n");
        functor_ = new functor_t(other.functor_);
    }

    entity(entity&& other) {
        printf("entity(entity&&)\n");
        functor_ = new functor_t(std::move(other.functor_));
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto operator=(T&& other) -> entity& {
        entity{std::forward<T>(other)}.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    auto swap(entity& other) -> void {
        std::swap(functor_, other.functor_);
    }

    functor_t* functor_ = nullptr;
};

int main() 
{
    entity n;
    entity a{n};
    entity b;

    b = a;

    printf("--------------------\n");
}
```

Yields:

```
entity(T&&)
entity(T&&)
~entity()
--------------------
~entity()
~entity()
~entity()
```

Even though I don't want to call the universal constructor.

Comment: Your demo doesn't compile. Here's the typo: `remove_cvref` -> `remove_cvref_t`.

Comment: You didn't write the requires clause properly. `std::remove_cvref<T>` is 100% not same as `entity`. You meant to write `std::remove_cvref_t<T>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I believe it doesn't compile because he wrote `!std::same_as` instead of `!std::same_as_v`. `std::remove_cvref` produces a different class than intended but it's not a cause for compilation error.

Comment: @ALX23z - There is no `std::same_as_v` - `std::same_as` is a concept, not a trait class template.

Comment: @ALX23z you are thinking of [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the universal T&& constructor called when another constructor is more specific?

The template constructor is the best candidate for overload resolution because it doesn't require any conversions. The copy constructor accepts a reference to const qualified `T`, and the given expression is an lvalue of non-const `T` which requires an implicit conversion and hence that overload is less preferred.

> I have even explicitely excluded the entity type from the overload

The `requires` clause doesn't disqualify the template constructor because `std::same_as<std::remove_cvref<entity&>` is not the same class as `entity`. You probably intended to use `std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<entity&>` instead.

> how can I prevent it?

Fix the requires clause, as per previous paragraph.

Providing the constructor `entity(entity&)` would also work, but I don't recommend that approach.

Comment: Thanks. If I had a dollar for every time I've forgotten about the t in some type trait...